# Remove options from dojo comboBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

Does anyone have idea how to remove options from dijit.form.ComboBox, I know how to do it from select, but the same principle is not working here. I could not find anything in the doc api. I tried with dojo.empty, same luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a store with your dijit.form.ComboBox? If so (and the store is writable) you should be able to remove an item from the store and therefore the ComboBox should reflect those changes.

```
store.fetch({ 
    query: {id: "123145"},
    onComplete: function(item_array) {
        store.deleteItem(item_array[0])
    }
});
```

I know this works when using a dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore and a FilteringSelect (which is very similar to a ComboBox). If you used declarative markup, the ComboBox might convert the html s to a data store and you might be able to find that store and do the same.

Also, I'm most familiar with v1.6 of the dojo toolkit. Newer versions use better data store types probably and they will probably have a more straightforward ways of deleting an item from a store than the older ItemFileWriteStore.

Answer (score 0):

After invoking the code given by flauerpower, call:

reset() method on the combobox. This will also clear the selection.

1) Dojo Controls are store aware
2) reset will clear the text/selection from the control.

hope  that helps